# Swift 4.2 parse json to use it on UIPickerview

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uipickerview, swifty-json

I want to use a json to show a picker view with one field of the json

```
data = {
        account = {
             id=0;
             accountNumber:534534535;
             institution:"bank1";
             balance:800.3;
          };
        account = {
                 id=1;
                 accountNumber:8353454535;
                 institution:"bank2";
                 balance:1200.87;
              }
        account = {
                 id=2;
                 accountNumber:31231231;
                 institution:"bank3";
                 balance:150.3;
              }
    };
```

For the json of accounts I've tried

```
var accounts:[AccountResponse] = []

let jsonAccounts = response["data"]
                let userAccounts = jsonAccounts["accounts"]
                for acc in userAccounts{
                    accounts = AccountResponse(accountResponse: acc)//doesn't work
                }
```

don't know how to use it as array to set it on the UIPickerView, wants to display bank1,bank2,bank3

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return accounts.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int) -> String? {
        return accounts[row]
    }
```

[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MTog.png)

**the purpose is to allow the user select the name and display the balance on the texview, also I would like to have the id stored in a variable**

I'm really new in swift, Previously I'm consuming a service and it returns json, before someone helped me with the dependency SwiftyJSON. I used it to get user information.

```
data =     {
    email = "vpozo@email.com";
    fullName = "Victor Pozo";
    id = 6;
    phoneNumber = 099963212;
    token = 6;
};
```

Now I can have it as an Object using

```
      let userJson = response["data"]
      let user = UserResponse(userResponse:userJson)
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that the *JSON* is not JSON the value for key `data` is invalid because a dictionary (no, it's not an array) must have unique keys. And you are encouraged to use built-in `Codable` (no dependencies at all) and drop SwiftyJSON

Comment: @vadian Well this dependency helped me to get the information, Codable didn't, but the main problem is that I would like to use a JSON on a pickerView, that's why I created this post.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the accounts anywhere at the moment.

```
accounts = AccountResponse(accountResponse: acc)
```

should be something like

```
accounts.append(AccountResponse(accountResponse: acc))
```

Comment: Allready tried it, but message:
'Cannot convert value of type '(String, JSON)' to expected argument type 'JSON''
But real problem is how to use it on the pickerview